# android ListView.getChildAt(i) is returning null from second time onwards

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I am having listview of contactNames and trying to move to the next alphabet of the contact when user swipe to the right. 
Ex:when anthony is there on the screen and when user swipes it should show the contact name starting with "b" .

So i am doing this:

```
 public void onSwipeRight() {
        final int offset = (int) (osList.getHeight() * .035f);
        //osList.smoothScrollToPositionFromTop(20,offset);
        Log.d("SwipeRight", "onFling: ");
        int lastPosition =osList.getLastVisiblePosition();
        viewHolder temp = (viewHolder)osList.getChildAt(lastPosition).getTag();
        String textValue = (String) temp.name.getText();
        osList.smoothScrollToPositionFromTop(getindexofnextAlphabet("textValue"),offset);

    }
```

But for the first time when i swipe getchildat is working but from second time onwards its returning null.

Comment: getLastVisiblePosition() `Returns the position within the adapter's data set for the last item displayed on screen`, and not the position of last visible child (View).
Try this: osList.getChildAt(osList.getChildCount() -1).getTag();
[getLastVisiblePosition](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getLastVisiblePosition%28%29)

Comment: Or you can get the string from the object in the last visible position, adapter.getItem(lastPosition)...

Comment: Thank you so much . I didn't knew about adapter.getItem(lastPosition). I am new Android Programming. For my actual post, inititally when the screen is loaded with Items 1 to 10, using getChildAt() i am getting the tag of Item 10 but when i scroll and when i could see 20th element on the screen but trying to use getchildAt() is giving null pointer. Why does it behave differently from the first time to second time?

Comment: Your listview show 10 items at the time, so it's index is always from 0 to 9. When you scroll to the 20th (as last item on screen) item the getLastVisiblePosition() will return you the index 19, because it is the position of the shown element of the adapter/array.
getChildAt(lastposition) is, in this case getchildAt(19) and as the listview only has 10 childs, it return's null, as stated in docummentation: [getChild()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#getChildAt%28int%29)

Comment: Got it . but even when i try this osList.getChildAt(osList.getChildCount() -1).getTag(); as said by you,still getting null pointer exception.

Answer (score 0):

First you must calculate the position (position means, position of first contact starting with "b" in `ArrayList`). For that you can store the number of contacts starting with "a", "b" and so on in an `ArrayList`.

So suppose on swipe you want to jump to the first contact starting with "b", then its position in the `ArrayList` is equal to the number of contacts starting with "a".

Now we have the position we want to jump to. I assume that `osList` is your `ListView`.

1. First calculate the number of views that can be occupied on screen. For that we need to calculate `pos1`, which is the position of Top Visible View on screen and `pos2`, which is the position of Last Visible View on screen:

   ```
   pos1 = osList.getFirstVisiblePosition()
   pos2 = osList.getLastVisiblePosition()
   ```

   Now the number of views that can be occupied (not accurate) on screen is `numScreenViews = pos2 - pos1 - 1`. here -1 is to eliminate the possibility that any view is partially visible. After all we have a rough idea.
2. Now inside `osSwipeRight()`:

   ```
   public void onSwipeRight() {
     osList.smoothScrollToPostion(min(noOfContact -1, 
                                      position + numScreenViews));
   }
   ```

   You don't need to use `getChildAt()` here, however if you want to get the posOnScreen(I am calling it `posOnScreen` because it's not the position in the `ArrayList` as clarified by @Joel) of first visible contact starting with "b", again calculate `pos1`, then calculate `posOnScreen` = position of your view (here position of first contact starting with alphabet "b" in arrayList) - pos1.